# Player disapearing after changing x scale

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the player turn around in Unity, and to so I have to change the x axis on the scale to a minus but the player disappears on doing so!
Here is my code:

```
void Update () 
{
    anim.SetBool ("Grounded", grounded);
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < -0.1f) 
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1f) 
    {
        print ("going right");
    }
```

Also there is a message written in the box collider whenever the player disappears it says "The collider to not make any collisions shapes as they were all failed verification..."

The player only disappears when moving left or right, this has really stumped me so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: If anyone sees this post it'll be really useful because I still have not got an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the *scale* of the player not the position. You are setting the players y and z scale to zero which will shrink them to be invisible. Try this:

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < -0.1f) 
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
}
if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1f) 
{
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: How so? can you explain a little more what the problem is? and what you are after?

Comment: The player defiantly doesn't go really small and as I said at the end of my post the box collider displays a message, I have no clue what's going on with my player

Comment: The player doesn't go really small. The player disappears as their 'height' and 'depth' are set to 0. That is why you can't see your player. The  error you are getting is because the boxcollider becomes too small. i.e it's height is also set to 0

Comment: I've changed the height and depth to 1 and it still does not work.

Comment: without seeing the rest of your code I can't really help any further man, In this snippet that you posted, that was your problem. I recommend checking that you aren't setting the players localscale anywhere else in code and that they are set to (1,1,1) in the inspector. Also check that the BoxCollider's size isn't set to 0 in the inspector. This is 100% an issue with scale being set incorrectly though. If you want to see the error being created then go to the box collider in the inspector and set it's size to 0. The error pops up underneath. Best of luck sorting this dude. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of comments about this but I will hold off on those and answer your question.

Main thing, when you check if the horizontal axis is less than -0.1f, you set the scale to (1,0,0). That means the y and z scales are 0 which makes it disappear. You have made it infinitely small in the y and z axis. Remember, if you set scale on any xis to 0, the object will no longer be visible. Also the 1 for the x value will not change which way the character appears to face at all. If you change that to -1.0 however, the character will appear to flip.

Secondly but you probably know this and were doing this for testing, when testing if the horizontal axis is greater than 0, all you do is print and that wont do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You question says you are looking to change the players position, but you are not actually changing it in your code.  Instead you are changing the scale of the object with this line (I'm not sure why gjttt1 suggeted this is what you WANT to do in his answer):

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
```

I suspect what you want is something more like this to change **position:**

```
transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
```

This will ADD vector 1,0,0 to your current position vector,

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but this is making the player go thin and taller not making the player spin around.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix it, it turns out my sprite was already really big so I must of made the sprite smaller earlier on, so in turn the sprite became really small... so small that the box collider couldn't detect it. So all I had to do was change the actual sprite size (the one in the assets). It was changed from 18000 to 18...